# How to transfer text from one excel file to another using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have done this process many times in macros in excel but this is the first time trying to do it using vb.net and can't figure it out. I have an xlsx with rows and columns of data in it. I would like to transfer the data over to a template that I made that has graphs waiting for the data. The data needs to go to the sheet2, this file is a xlsm (read only). Nothing that I have tried from vba will work in vb.net. different syntax. Help.

The code I have so far:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core
Public Class Form1
Private Sub cbo_FileList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbo_FileList.Click
    Dim folderpath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump"
    cbo_FileList.Items.Clear()
    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderpath)
        cbo_FileList.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Do_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Do.Click
    Dim txtpath As String
    Dim csvpath As String = "C:\Temp"
    Dim FileTXT As String
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim FinalFile As String


    folderpath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump"
    FileTXT = cbo_FileList.Text
    csvpath = "C:\Temp\" & FileTXT & ".csv"
    txtpath = folderpath & "\" & FileTXT & ".txt"
    FinalFile = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Book1"

    File.Copy(txtpath, csvpath)
    Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", csvpath)
    Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", FinalFile)

 'Need to have copy past and close here
    'File.Delete(csvpath)

 End Sub
 End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EPPlus (you can get this via nuget package manager) ... It´s a complete xlsx handling lib very useful for handling that.

There are also closed source libs, and also Excel Interop would be possible - but would need installed Office.

I used it already to make some customers happy

Comment: I cant just download stuff, my company has all that locked down.

Comment: If Office is installed - Excel Interop. Hard way but possible.

Comment: Otherwise, tell your Company: Either you get your lib, or they won´t get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to copy data from one workbook to another:

```
Public Sub CopyData()

    Dim ExcelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    Dim WB1, WB2 As Workbook



    Try

        'optional
        ExcelApp.Visible = False


        'open both workbooks
        WB1 = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\File1.xlsx")
        WB2 = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\File2.xlsx")


        'rows
        For r As Integer = 1 To 5

            'columns
            For c As Integer = 1 To 5

                'copy the value of the cell
                WB2.Sheets(2).Cells(r, c).Value = WB1.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Value

                'or text:
                'WB2.Sheets(2).Cells(r, c).Text = WB1.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Text

            Next

        Next


        'save the second workbook
        WB2.Save()


        'close the workbooks
        WB1.Close()
        WB2.Close()


        'and quit the Excel application
        ExcelApp.Quit()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        ExcelApp.Quit()

    End Try

End Sub
```